# Steppermotor+Arduino Mega+ Adafruit

Tags: arduino-mega, adafruit, stepper

I have 2 Stepper Motors (QMot stepper motor1 Amp, 5.3Ohms, 5.3 volts and 200 steps/rev.)
, which are connected to the Adafruit shield2.4, they are mounted to Arduino Mega, the motors pull generally 2 A from external current from Adafruit. My problem is, they don´t rotate smoothly, clearly and fast at the same time.
When I use DOUBLE to define my Stepps, speed is ok but rotation is lout and shaking. When I use MICROSTEP is more smoothly but too much slow. The program is running two stepper motors to roll up optical cables. The cables have to be really precisely come together and accurately be installed on pulley. 
Also I need a solution to run my Steppers Motors smoothly, clearly and fast.
Incidentally, I want to know, do I need BigEasyDriver for that? 
 If you need more info oder fotos feel free to ask

Regards,

Paria

Comment: What's an Adafruit shield2.4? Where is your code?

Comment: Adafruit do hundreds of shields. Many of them have multiple versions. ***WHAT*** shield is it?!?!

Comment: If you have two motors that always need to do the same thing at the same time why are you controlling two motors.  It would be easy to splice [which means join] the two motors control wires together,

Comment: adafruit motor shield v 2.3

Comment: my motors do diffrent things at the same time. I have to control the speed of second Motor, this motor shakes always according to its duty, that is too bad,  I don´t know how to let it running smoothly and fast. With MICROSTEPS is too slowly and with DOUBLE is shaking...
what should I do?

can I begin with MICROSTEPS and change it into Double and again in MICROSTEPS at the end. Because the Motor have to roll up cabels. The cables have to be really precisely come together, because of that I need Smoothly running, specially at the beginning and at the end....

Comment: And your code...? Or do I have to ask you for that ten times as well?

Comment: my code is too long, and it is impossible to post it hier !!!! I have tried 10 times...

Comment: as an anwser i have postet, if you can read it....

Comment: That is not how to do it. I suggest you [read the help files](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and edit your question adding the code properly. Delete your answer. An answer is not the place to add information pertaining to your question.

Comment: `it is impossible to post it hier` - edit the question and post the code. Use code formatting (four leading spaces). For help see [Markdown help](http://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help). You should be able to do this by selecting the code and pressing `Ctrl+K` to have your browser do this for you.

Answer (score 3):

I'd look for a proper stepper driver, e.g. something based on A4988 or similar. I wasted a fair amount of time on the Adafruit motor-shield 2.3 until I finally abandoned it after failing to achieve higher speeds (I also had lots of issues with the motor getting hot). The A4988 takes care of step sequencing including micro-stepping and interfacing and programming is very simple. It only comes in surface-mount packaging but there are bread-board friendly carriers costing a few dollars available from multiple manufacturers.